# Stack around variable is corrupted error

Tags: c++

I am writing the following code and I am getting `Stack around variable is corrupted` error. I have checked similar posts but couldn't relate the problems. I am also rather new to C++. Here is my code.

```
///CLASS DEFINITION
class Trellis{

    private:
        int m;
        int Nstates;
        int StateTransition[];

    public:
        Trellis(); 
        Trellis(int M);
};
```

Here is the definition of methods

```
Trellis::Trellis(int M){
    m = M;
    Nstates = pow(2, M - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < Nstates; i++){
        StateTransition[i] = i;
    }
}
```

int main()
{

```
Trellis Tu = Trellis(3);
```

return 0;
}

The error I get is Run-Time Check Failure #2-Stack around variuble 'Tu' was corrupted;

Comment: StateTransition doesn't look right...

Comment: You should provide the entire error with message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flexible array members](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzarg/flexible.htm) were a C99 feature which allowed you to do something like

```
struct header {
    size_t len;
    unsigned char data[];
};
```

and, provided that you had a proper memory layout, you could access and write to the `data` array.

In your case you're not providing any memory for your `StateTransition` variable and thus overwriting some other stack data.

You had better doing something like

```
class Trellis
{
private:
  int m;
  int Nstates;
  int *StateTransition; // Pointer

public:
  Trellis(); 
  Trellis(int M);
  ~Trellis();
};
Trellis::Trellis() : StateTransition(0) {
}
Trellis::Trellis(int M) : StateTransition(0)
{
  m = M;
  Nstates = pow(2, M - 1);

  StateTransition = new int[Nstates]; // Allocate memory

  for (int i = 0; i < Nstates; i++)
  {
    StateTransition[i] = i;
  }
}

Trellis::~Trellis() {
    if(StateTransition != 0)
        delete[] StateTransition; // Always be a good citizen
}
```

And as for the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three), you might also want to write a copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You're not allocating any memory for `StateTransition`, you want something like:

```
StateTransition = new int[Nstates];
```

before your `for` loop in the ctor.

Comment: @user63050 Did you get a different error message after making the change?  Please provide the entire error message in your question post.

Comment: I updated the post. The new error I am getting is  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int []'

Comment: @user63050 An array might decay into a pointer but not in this case, use an int*